# Equivalence of Topological Quantum Computing and the Quantum Circuit Model

Tags: resource-request, quantum-circuit

It is my understanding that topological quantum computers are capable of executing an arbitrary quantum circuit with a polynomial overhead of translating the circuit to the native topological operations.

What is the tightest bound on this translation? Any references?

Comment: Check out https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0001071, theorem 2.2